# OpenGL ES Android Particle System rendering 2d interface becomes translucent

Tags: opengl-es, particle-system

[image]

The order of drawing will affect the results, the model's texture will become translucent, but the 2d interface is always translucent,

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and formulate properly your problem

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you left your additive blend mode on after rendering your particles. Try:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Before you render your interface.